# Remote SSH from VSCode to Google Cloud VMs over IAP tunnel

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, vscode-remote-ssh

I am using the below command for SSH to GCP VMs. How can I configure VSCode to use these settings?

```
gcloud beta compute ssh --zone "asia-south1-a" "jump-box" --tunnel-through-iap --project "Project Name"
```

*(editor note: notice `--tunnel-through-iap` in particular)*

Comment: It might be just me ... but I don't know what you mean by "... configure this as per remote SSH config?" ... could you elaborate on what you mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

Given the title I'm guessing what you're trying to do is use a `compute ssh` command for https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh

I couldn't find a way to use this directly, but a workaround that I found is to run:

```
gcloud compute config-ssh --dry-run --project "Project Name"
```

This will produce an SSH configuration for all the instances in your project.

I was then able to add the hosts I was interested to my vscode ssh config (`~/.ssh/config` by default). It'll be something like this, but I've redacted the bits related to my project.

```
Host INSTANCE-NAME.ZONE.PROJECT_NAME
    HostName IP
    IdentityFile /Users/USER/.ssh/google_compute_engine
    UserKnownHostsFile=/Users/USER/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts
    HostKeyAlias=compute.ID
    IdentitiesOnly=yes
    CheckHostIP=no
```

You could also omit the `--dry-run` to automatically add the entries.

Answer (score 1):

https://medium.com/@albert.brand/remote-to-a-vm-over-an-iap-tunnel-with-vscode-f9fb54676153 provides a tutorial. Briefly, add `--dry-run` to your normal `gcloud compute ssh` command to see what gcloud is doing under the hood. Those options need to get set in your VSCode SSH config file.

When using `--tunnel-through-iap`, you'll see a few `ProxyCommand` that invokes gcloud.py, and `HostName` and `HostKeyAlias` set to the instance ID (looks like `compute.123456789123456789`), as well as a few others.